# Swift full date with milliseconds

Tags: ios, swift

Is any way to print full date with milliseconds?

For example, I'm doing this:

```
print("\(NSDate())")
```

But I'm just get this:

```
2016-05-09 22:07:19 +0000
```

How can I get the milliseconds too in the full date?

Comment: You need to use `NSDateFormatter` with the proper `dateFormat`. Printing the actual date object gives you the string representation for the date in UTC, not necessarily the time zone you are interested in.

Comment: You can use `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` to get milliseconds

Comment: @YuriRomanchenko `timeIntervalSince1970` returns seconds not milliseconds.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
let d = Date()
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSSS"

df.string(from: d) // -> "2016-11-17 17:51:15.1720"
```

When you have a `Date` `d`, you can get the formatted string using a NSDateFormatter. You can also use a formatter to turn a string date based on your format into a `Date`

See this chart for more on what dateFormat can do http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Comment: That's a very misleading format since you make the fractional seconds look like a timezone. A much better format would be to have `ss.SSS` at the end instead of `ss +SSSS`.

Comment: You also have the wrong format for the year. Use `yyyy`, not `Y`.

Comment: I agree about the seconds using the ss.SSSS format but it looked like that's what they were asking for? I'll edit my answer in case someone comes across this and just copy pastes. As per the year comment, Y returns the ISO 8601 spec year.

Comment: Read the docs for `y` and `Y`. They are two different years. 99.99% of the time a person wants `y`, not `Y`. And what makes you think the OP wants the milliseconds formatted like a timezone? They are simply showing the standard output of printing a date (which shows the timezone offset by default) and asks how to add milliseconds to that output. That doesn't mean they want the milliseconds formatted like a timezone.

Comment: `Y` is wrong. it will return the year of a week-based calendar. A subtle error that even apple [got wrong before](https://alexander.kirk.at/2011/01/11/ios-2011-alarm-clock-bug/).

Comment: I created a snippet that proves `Y` is wrong: https://gitlab.com/snippets/19107 It just creates a date from a string and than creates a string form the date — and the year is off by 1. if you change the `Y` from the format to `y` the result is correct.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `y-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS` (only 3 `S`) for milliseconds?

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5** to/from Timestamp String Extension

```
extension String {
    static func timestamp() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSS"
        let now = Date.now

        return String(format: "%@", dateFormatter.string(from: now))
    }

    func tad2Date() -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSS"
    
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}
```